# no output from ffmpeg

Tags: node.js, macos, command-line, ffmpeg

I am trying to convert a .mov file to a .mp4 file

this is my command

```
ffmpeg -v 0 -i ./sample.mov -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=0 -c:v libx264 -f mp4 -c:a libfdk_aac ./mov.mp4
```

this does not give any output and does not convert the file.

I tried converting a .caf file to an mp3 and it worked with

```
ffmpeg -i ./sample.caf ./sample.mp3
```

it gave output and it converted the file.

What I'm trying to do is getting the code from php and run it on a node js file

This is my nodejs code:

```
var runner = require('child_process');
runner.exec('ffmpeg -v 0 -i '+file_location+' -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=0 -c:v libx264 -f mp4 -c:a libfdk_aac '+file_location.replace('.mov', '.mp4'), function(err, stdout, stderr){
    console.log(err, stdout, stderr)
})
```

this translates directly to the first command.
The stderr is empty, the stdout is empty, and the err is:

```
{ Error: Command failed: THE COMMAND

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:206:12)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
  killed: false,
  code: 1,
  signal: null,
  cmd: THE COMMAND
  }
```

So how should I solve this? On the terminal i have no output, but with node i have output, but it's not helpful

Comment: Show the full console output of the failed command.

Comment: that is the full output

Comment: Ah, you have `-v 0`, use `-v 32` and check.

Comment: god damn it i'm blind

Comment: Unrelated, but `-metadata:s:v:0 rotate=0` is likely superfluous because `ffmpeg` will autorotate if needed and will afterwards strip the rotate metadata.